# How to truncate the beginning of all columns in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with quite a few different columns (4800+) and they are all named after file directories. For example, I can have two columns named:

`Return.ReturnData.IRS990.EOYAmount` and `Return.ReturnData.IRS990PF.EOYAmount` as you can see the only difference is at `IRS990/IRS990PF`. But these two columns contain similar data so I want tor rename them both to `EOYAmount`.

Obviously I have a couple thousand files so I can't do this for every single one but I wanted to know how to truncate everything before the last period? If anybody has any suggestions please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```py
import re

rename_pattern = r'.*\.' # will remove everything until 
                         # the last . in name (greedy regex, longest match)

# applies the lambda mapper 
# function to all columns and replaces the rename_pattern with an empty string
df = df.rename(columns=lambda col_name: re.sub(rename_pattern,'',col_name))
```

**Edit:**

To keep only a part of the column names you can alter the above given code as follows:

```py
import re

rename_pattern = r'(.*?\.){2}' 

df = df.rename(columns=lambda col_name: re.sub(rename_pattern,'',col_name))
```

The `( )` in the `rename_pattern` groups the regular expression and allows to specify the occurence quantity with the trailing `{2}`.
If your path is longer and you have to delete a longer pattern you can alter this `2` with any number you like.
Another change is to make `.*` matching non-greedy with `?`.
This will result in only matching one word followed by a dot.

An alternation to `r'(.*?\.){2}'` will be `r'(\w+\.){2}'`

Comment: Simple enough, I appreciate the quick response! Thank you!

Comment: Quick question, I'm not too familiar with re. How would I get rid of everything before the SECOND to last . ?

Comment: Only the directory/ file names `IRS990` and `IRS990PF` in your example?

Comment: So in my example they would be `IRS990.EOYAmount` and `IRS990PF.EOYAmount` But in reality I have much more files so it could also be something like `IRS990ScheduleD.Investments`

Comment: I updated my answer and added additional information

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate the new insight and advice!

Comment: You are welcome. If you are further interested in regular expressions in Python you can look at this [guide](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)